# Installing optional Nginx modules with apt-get

Tags: nginx, apt, package-management

I currently have Nginx installed via the instructions on the Nginx site:

```
nginx=stable
sudo su -
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx
apt-get update 
apt-get install
```

I have configured Nginx and it has been running great for a little while. Now, I want to add some custom modules--say, the [Upload Progress Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule). The instructions for this module say to add `--add-module=path/to/nginx_uploadprogress_module` to your `./configure` command. However, I did not install Nginx from source.

What is the best way to handle this situation? Is it possible to tell APT to compile from source and pass options to `./configure`? Can I compile over the existing installation? What about paths--how do I make them match? Or do I have to remove the APT managed version and start over?

Comment: Did you look for the needed module using `apt-cache search`?

Comment: nginx solid, it not support dynamic module.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Install dpkg-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

Add repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-lucid.list`, add dpkg-src:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu lucid main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu lucid main
```

note: (the previous step may have already been automatically performed on Ubuntu >= 12.04 - also make sure that you change `lucid` to reflect your version)

Resynchronize the package index files:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Get sources:

```
apt-get source nginx
```

Build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nginx
```

Edit nginx-0.8.54/debian/rules:

```
config.status.full: config.env.full config.sub config.guess
...
--add-module=path/to/nginx_uploadprogress_module
```

Build package:

```
cd nginx-0.8.54 && dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

Install packages:

```
sudo dpkg --install nginx-common_1.2.4-2ubuntu0ppa1~precise_all.deb

sudo dpkg --install nginx-full_1.2.4-2ubuntu0ppa1~precise_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Wonderful, detailed instructions. At the end, while `sudo dpkg --install nginx-full_0.8.54-4ppa4~lucid_i386.deb`-ing, I'm receiving `nginx-full depends on nginx-common (= 0.8.54-4ppa4~lucid); however: Package nginx-common is not installed.` However, `sudo dpkg --install nginx-common_0.8.54-4ppa4~lucid_all.deb` is giving `dpkg: error processing nginx-common_0.8.54-4ppa4~lucid_all.deb (--install): trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html', which is also in package nginx 0:0.8.54-4ppa2~lucid`. How would you recommend resolving this issue?

Comment: Remove nginx package: apt-get remove nginx

Comment: In this particular case, is there any advantage to installing in this manner over compiling from source by hand? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi alvosu, I'm getting this error: dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2. Any idea?

Comment: @BrandonTilley if you install it this way, you can uninstall it via `apt-get`/`dpkg`, and also other packages that you install via `apt-get` will know that `nginx` is installed and will not ask you to install it. If you installed it directly from source you won't get this.

Comment: If you have error like this "dpkg-buildpackage: warning: Failed to sign .dsc and .changes file", use `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us` instead of `dpkg-buildpackage -b`. Otherwise, .deb files won't be created.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer... It worked like charm!

Comment: Tried following the steps and on `dpkg-buildpackage -b` it gave me at the end: `dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5 (used by debian/nginx-full/usr/sbin/nginx).`

Answer (score 40):

[Since squeeze in Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/nginx-extras) and [since oneric](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/nginx-extras) in Ubuntu, there are [some](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/nginx-extras) (like `headers-more-module` I needed) in

```
apt-get install nginx-extras
```

Comment: Dotdeb provides a nice nginx-extras package: http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/

Comment: For nginx-plus version, apt-get install nginx-extras works great, too! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Installing Nginx from source is necessary if you want to add extra/(third party module) to it. If installed via source the Nginx can't be used as a service and logrotate doesn't gets setup for Nginx. Follow this [method](http://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2016/05/add-module-to-nginx.html) to get it installed with all functionalities which you get from installing via `apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

Sweet article that can be read [here](https://serversforhackers.com/compiling-third-party-modules-into-nginx) will explain the detailed information on compiling modules into nginx. Basically you need to recompile the nginx each time you want to install a module.

Also similar to this [method](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation) will also work.

```
 wget 'http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.3.tar.gz'
 tar -xzvf nginx-1.9.3.tar.gz
 cd nginx-1.9.3/

 # Here we assume you would install you nginx under /opt/nginx/.
 ./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx \
     --add-module=/path/to/headers-more-nginx-module
 make
 make install
```